# How can I change the name of my C++ application in Visual Studio 2013 (The name that appears at the top of the window)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have tried changing the name of the active project, the solution, and the root directory of the project, but none of these affect the name that appears on the application window when I launch it. I have looked through the solution and project properties and haven't found a field that I can change.

I have found answers to this question that apply to VS 2010 and 2008 but they do not apply to 2013.

EDIT: I am referring to the GUI window created by the application with DirectX.

Comment: The title of a window doesn't have anything to do with the language you're using (or the development environment). Are you talking about a command line window or a GUI window you created as part of your application? In the latter case, please specify what GUI library you are using.

Comment: You could always change it programmaticly, with `SetWindowText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The name was being read in from a .rc file!

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding with the DirectX API, the title of the window should be passed to`CreateWindowEx`.

```
       CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                      name_of_win_class,    
                      title_goes_here,  
                      window_style,   
                      x_pos,   
                      win_wid,    
                      win_hei,    
                      parent_win,   
                      menus,    
                      app_handle,    
                      mul_wins);
```